# In a bounded set of Person, there must be someone without a father, right?

Tags: alloy

The following model is for persons and their fathers. The "fact" says that no person can be his own father, nor can a person be the father of his father, the father of his father's father, and so forth. The "assert" says that every person has a father. The "check" command invites the Alloy Analyzer to find a counterexample. Note that no bound is specified on the "check" command; therefore the Analyzer defaults to 3 persons in the Person set.

When I run the "check" command the Analyzer says "No counterexample found." But I can provide a counterexample: Let the set of Person be {(Tom), (John), (Ken)}. The father of Tom is Ken. The father of John is Ken. But Ken's father is not in the Person set (Ken's father cannot be Tom or John per the "fact" statement, and there are no other persons per the default bound of 3). So isn't this a counterexample?

```
sig Person {father: Person}

fact {
    no p: Person | p in p.^father
}

assert Every_Person_Has_A_Father {
   all p: Person | some p.father
}

check Every_Person_Has_A_Father
```

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed counter-example is not allowed by the model: sig Person forces everyone to have a father (father : Person); so your assertion is true.

Try sig Person{father : lone Person} instead.

Comment: Thanks but that does not answer my question. The "run" command is bounded to (the default) 3 person values. Given that bound, it's not possible for every person to have a father (and conform to the constraint that no person can be his own father, or his father's father). Right?

Comment: There is only one valid solution to your model: the empty solution (no instances at all). And the empty solution is not a counter-example to the assertion.

Comment: Wow! @wmeyer than you very much. Awesome insight!